# Using Visual Studio C++ compiler w/ Meson?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, meson-build

I'm trying to use https://github.com/Pizzabelly/EasyRP to create a desktop application, and I need a C++ compiler to continue. It says to download "any c++ compiler (cl, g++, clang++, etc)", and I'm wondering if I have to download a new package/directory to continue, or if there's a way to use something from Visual Studio 2019 (which I'm using for code development).

Thanks in advance. I'm a total newbie.

Comment: cl is the name of the compiler used by default by Visual Studio.

Comment: Hmm, I've changed the compiler name in meson.build to 'cl', but it's still giving me an 'Unknown compiler' error when I try to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed https://mesonbuild.com/Using-with-Visual-Studio.html along with https://github.com/Pizzabelly/EasyRP. Make sure to use the VS command line. Also, EasyRP says to run `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release`, and I had to add `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release ALLBUILD.vcxproj` so that it would properly build.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.